# SSAS backup script fails in job, but works in query window

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm backing up an SSAS database using the code below, but keep getting this error:  *Incorrect syntax near '<'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.*

The command, as shown below, works perfectly in the query window, and in fact was scripted from the wizard. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>MyDatabaseName</DatabaseID>
  </Object>
  <File>MyDatabaseName.abf</File>
  <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
  <ApplyCompression>false</ApplyCompression>
</Backup>
```

**edit 1**: I've now set the job step to SQL Server Analysis Services Command, and am getting a different error: *An exception (0xe0434f4d) occurred in the ANALYSISCOMMAND subsystem.  The step failed.*

**edit 2**: I've tried Jason's suggestion, to add an output file via the advanced tab of the job step, but no file was outputted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the subsytem in the job step from T-SQL to XML for Analysis Services (XMLA).  Edit the job, then edit the job step and there will be a drop down to change the subsystem.

Whoops, didn't see the edit.  On the advanced tab of the job step properties you can select an output file.  Set that up, see if that gives you a less generic error to work with, and post back.

Comment: I set it, but the file isn't produced.